# How do I simplify the hypernegation in Ontario Human Rights Code, RSO 1990, s. 24?

Tags: legalese, multiple-negation

> [(2) No tribunal or court shall find that a qualification under clause (1) (b) is reasonable and bona fide unless it is satisfied that the circumstances of the person cannot be accommodated without undue hardship on the person responsible for accommodating those circumstances considering the cost, outside sources of funding, if any, and health and safety requirements, if any.](https://canlii.ca/t/2fd#sec24)

How to unscramble all this hypernegation tripping me up? I start simplifying by deleting synonyms, and abbreviating nouns.

Tribunals are like courts, so I delete tribunal.
I feel like overlooking clause (1)(b)., ***but I don't know if I can do this ?***
'Reasonable' is more recognizable than Latin 'bona fide', so I delete 'bona fide'.
Most judges are intelligent. If a judge is satisfied that Φ, then Φ is true. So I delete "it is satisfied that".
Call "the person responsible for accommodating those circumstances ...." accommodator.

> No <s>tribunal or</s> court shall find that a qualification <s>under clause (1) (b)</s> is reasonable <s>and bona fide</s> [UNLESS](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/30643) <s>it is satisfied that</s> the circumstances of the person cannot be accommodated without undue hardship on the accommodator.

No court shall find that a qualification is reasonable. = Each court shall find that a qualification is unreasonable.
X cannot be accommodated without Y. = X can be accommodated only with Y.
I feel these equalities are true.  But I am no logician. I cannot prove these equalities mathematically.  ***Are my guesses correct?***

> Every court shall find that a qualification is unreasonable [UNLESS](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/27053)  the circumstances of the person can be accommodated only with undue hardship on the accommodator.

I know [UNLESS](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/55923)  [= IF NOT](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/16019), so I substitute out [UNLESS](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/56053). ***Are all my steps correct so far?***

> Every court shall find that a qualification is unreasonable IF NOT the circumstances of the person can be accommodated only with undue hardship on the accommodator.

Now what? How do I finish simplifying?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is on topic, as even a native speaker will have difficulty understanding and simplifying legalese. The steps you've made are logically coherent (though the "IF NOT" change actually makes it less readable). That said, through the process of logical simplification, you've actually lost what the courts are being ordered to do. Ordering a courts not to make a finding is actually legally different than ordering courts to make a negative finding.

Comment: I would paraphrase it as, "Courts must not find that an exception to workplace discrimination requirements is reasonable unless the requirements cause problems for the employer (cost, funding, safety, etc)". This is in addition to the requirement under 1b that it must be justified by the nature of the employment. I am not a lawyer, this is not legal advice.

Comment: I guess you can say, "Courts may find that an exception to workplace discrimination policies is reasonable only if it causes problems for the employer (cost, funding, safety, etc)" to get rid of the negatives, while still keeping in mind there are other requirements that must also be met.

Comment: I don't see this as an English Learning question.  If you want the law explained consult a lawyer.  If you interested learning about law try [law.se].   There are problems in paraphrasing laws, since the exact phrasing might be important, but only a lawyer can advise you on what is important for your situation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I suggest this be moved to the Law site. Although I don't know if it would be welcome there.

Comment: I was going to rewrite this but then decided not to as that is not our mission here. However, you need to **keep reasonable AND bona fide**. A tribunal **may not rule that a qualification is reasonable and bona fide** under ib unless etc.

Comment: Ask a lawyer.  Also, this isn't about learning English, and asking others to correct or improve wording is off-topic.

Comment: When you willy-nilly delete things, you can end up with a clause lacking a subject for its verb. That approach is unnecessary.

Comment: @BIllyKerr Your comment appears uncivil. This is definitely learning English. Kindly research the [legalese tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legalese) first, so that you do not mischaracterize questions.  I am not asking about law. I want to analyse syntax, [just like question on a EU regulation.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/225723), [this on the Health and Safety at Work Act](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/69894), and [this on a judgment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/76749).

Comment: @PeterJennings With respect, you are incorrect to vote to close this question, or migrate. This is an ESL question. I am not asking about law. I want to analyse syntax, [just like this question on EU regulation.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/225723), [this on Health and Safety at Work Act](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/69894), and [this on a judgment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/76749).  Did you research the [legalese tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legalese) before you commented?

Comment: @JamesK This is definitely an ESL question on topic. I do not want law explained.  I want to analyse syntax, [just like this question on EU regulation.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/225723), [this on Health and Safety at Work Act](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/69894), and [this on a judgment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/76749).  Did you research the [legalese tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legalese) before you commented?

Comment: @user959921 - nothing uncivil was intended.  Just stating facts. Improving/rewording text is off topic. And legal questions really belong on Law Stack exchange. Sorry if it sounded a bit blunt. That wasn't my intention. But you have an answer anyway.

Comment: @user95921  My comment stands.  If you paraphrase or simplify legal text you get a text which may, or may not be applicable to your needs.  If you want someone to explain the law to you, please consult a lawyer.  If you want to learn about the law, use [law.se]

Comment: @YonKuma This is definitely  an ESL question on topic. I do not want law explained.  I want to analyse syntax, [just like this question on EU regulation.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/225723), [this on Health and Safety at Work Act](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/69894), and [this on an Australian court judgment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/75327).  Did you research the [legalese tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legalese) before you commented?

Comment: @JamesK How does my question differ from the linked others? You did not address my linked questions. And see [this on an Australian court judgment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/75327).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**unless** introduces *necessary* conditions.

> You cannot log in unless you know the password.

Here, the conditions are those necessary for a judicial finding that a qualification is reasonable and bona fide.

```
No tribunal or court shall find [i.e. decide, rule]
   that a qualification under clause (1) (b) is reasonable and bona fide
    unless 
    it [the tribunal or court] is satisfied 
        that the circumstances of the person cannot be accommodated 
        without undue hardship on the person responsible for accommodating 
                those circumstances 

    considering [i.e. with the court or tribunal taking into account] 
            the cost,
            outside sources of funding, if any, 
            and health and safety requirements, if any.
```

To understand how **unless** works, flip the negative in the main clause and substitute "if" for "unless":

```
  A tribunal or court MAY find
   that a qualification under clause (1) (b) is reasonable and bona fide
  ONLY IF
  it [the tribunal or court] is satisfied  etc.
```

P.S. In legal contexts **shall** is synonymous with **must**. This is a *prohibition* affecting all courts:

> No court shall find...

The opposite of a prohibition is not a *requirement*:

> Each court shall find... <sup>wrong</sup>

but a *permission*:

> Each court **may** find ...

Comment: Unexplained downvotes are of little educational value.

Comment: I'd suggest "ONLY IF" for the rewording, as it maintains the necessity of the condition (unrelated to the downvote)

Comment: Yes, "only if" is idiomatic.  Not sure OP would understand what "only" meant. But I'll edit.

Comment: @TimR I did not down vote you.

Comment: @user95921      (No court shall  find  * -1 ) = A court may find